# Why does my profile reputation "by post" view show the same information as the "by time" view?

Tags: support, stack-overflow, user-interface

I love the new reputation views in the users section of Stack Overflow but I am confused about why the "by post" and "by time" views under the reputation tab both appear to show the same information?

I would have expected "by post" to break down the reputation in an identical way except that it would be in terms of posts.

Please could someone explain why this behaves the way that it does?

Sample screenshots:

[image: A screenshot of the "by post" view]

[image: A screenshot of the "by time" view]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Both views show your votes broken in to days.

The "by posts" or "by time" then performs a sub-sort on the data within each day.

So, since you only have one event on each day you have expanded in the screenshots there is no visible difference for you between the two options.

To see the intended difference in action try expanding one of the days where you have +25, or better yet check out someone who earns a *lot* of rep, like Jon Skeet's [by post](https://stackoverflow.com/users/22656/jon-skeet?tab=reputation#reppage_1-repview_post) and [by time](https://stackoverflow.com/users/22656/jon-skeet?tab=reputation#reppage_1-repview_time), then you'll see the difference.

Comment: That make's more sense. Thought that I must be missing something :)